# R: Using dplyr to create a dataframe with percentage per group

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm having trouble trying to create a new dataframe that creates a percentage per year with dplyr.

Dataframe is as follows:

```
    structure(list(orgid = c("USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-PA", "USGS-PA", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ"), stdate = structure(c(16134, 
16133, 16135, 16133, 16105, 15749, 16112, 16394, 16610, 16610, 
16511, 16560, 16566, 16328, 16324), class = "Date"), locid = c("USGS-01367785", 
"USGS-01455099", "USGS-01440000", "USGS-01380100", "USGS-01398000", 
"USGS-01461880", "USGS-0140940950", "USGS-01482500", "USGS-0146453250", 
"USGS-0146453250", "USGS-01444800", "USGS-01444800", "USGS-01477120", 
"USGS-01392150", "USGS-01376274"), charnam = c("Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids"), val = c("154", 
"333", "109", "143", "711", "218", "104", "157", "506", "471", 
"3040", "1110", "142", "429", "266")), .Names = c("orgid", "stdate", 
"locid", "charnam", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a new column with the percentage of each year's Total dissolved solids that is > 500.

Code I have so far:

```
if (!require(pacman)) {
  install.packages('pacman')

}

pacman::p_load("ggplot2","tidyr","plyr","dplyr")
#### Read in the necessary data ######
roadsalt_data<-read.table("QADportaldata_1988-2015.tsv",header=T,sep="\t",fill=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Convert date column from a character class to a date class so ggplot can  display as a continuous variable ###
roadsalt_data$stdate <- as.Date(roadsalt_data$stdate)
## Filter dataset to only contain columns I need ########
filtered_roadsalt <- roadsalt_data %>% 
  select(orgid, stdate,locid, charnam,val) %>%
  filter(between(stdate, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01"))) %>%
  filter(charnam == "Total dissolved solids" & as.numeric(as.character(val)) > 50.00)
##create a dataframe for percent of TDS >500
percent_data<-filtered_roadsalt %>%
  mutate(year=as.Date(cut(stdate, breaks = "year"))) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(prop = round(as.numeric(as.character(val))/sum(as.numeric(as.character(val)))*100, 2))
```

This however is not getting me the results I'm after.. The dataframe I want should have 19 observations and 2 variables. The 19 observations being each year from 1997-2015 and there percentage. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please `dput` your data here so this is reproducible

Comment: @camille edited it

Comment: Hadn't noticed this earlier, but you were also filtering for `as.numeric(as.character(val)) > 50.00`, when it sounds like you wanted `> 500`

Answer (score 2):

```
install.packages("scales")

scales::percent(2.842215e-03)

0.284%
```

See also `options(digits=)` and `options(scipen=)` for other strategies.

Comment: That only addresses the issue of formatting, not any of the calculations preceding printing

Comment: You should use scales::label_percent() in future code

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert `val` to numeric and retrieve the years for each date. This can be done with `lubridate::year`. `count` is a shorthand for grouping by variables and summarizing them where the only summary statistic you need is the number of observations. This may not be the case in your full dataset, but in the sample you posted, 2013 doesn't have any observations with values greater than 500, so there won't be a `(TRUE, 2013)` row in the summarized data. So I used `complete` to fill in a row to explicitly show 0 of those observations.

```r
library(tidyverse)

shares <- df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(val = as.numeric(val)) %>%
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(stdate)) %>%
  count(year, charnam, isOver500 = val > 500) %>%
  complete(isOver500, nesting(year, charnam), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  mutate(share = n / sum(n))

shares
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   isOver500  year charnam                    n  share
#>   <lgl>     <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 FALSE      2013 Total dissolved solids     1 0.0667
#> 2 FALSE      2014 Total dissolved solids     8 0.533 
#> 3 FALSE      2015 Total dissolved solids     2 0.133 
#> 4 TRUE       2013 Total dissolved solids     0 0     
#> 5 TRUE       2014 Total dissolved solids     1 0.0667
#> 6 TRUE       2015 Total dissolved solids     3 0.2

shares %>%
  filter(isOver500)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   isOver500  year charnam                    n  share
#>   <lgl>     <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 TRUE       2013 Total dissolved solids     0 0     
#> 2 TRUE       2014 Total dissolved solids     1 0.0667
#> 3 TRUE       2015 Total dissolved solids     3 0.2
```

Created on 2018-05-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting numbers like 2.842215e-03.. is there anyway to change this to an actual percentage?

Comment: That is an actual percentage...Round it off however you want, or change your global R options to print fewer decimal places or. If you want a format like 25% instead of 0.25, multiply by 100 and `paste0` a percent sign to it

Comment: Thanks! Your the best! @camille